# Most efficient data structure for a nested loop?

Tags: data-structures, nested-loops

I am iterating through each line in the first file (3000 lines total) to find it's corresponding label in the second file, line by line (which is ~2 million lines; 47 MB)

Currently, I have a nested loop structure with the outer loop grabbing a line (converting into a list) and the inner loop iterating through the 2 million lines (line by line):

```
for row in read_FIMO: #read_FIMO is first file; 3000 lines long
     with open("chr8labels.txt") as label: #2 million lines long  
         for line in csv.reader(label, delimiter="\t"): #list
            for i in range(int(row[3]),int(row[4])):  
                if i in  range((int(line[1])-50),int(line[1])):#compare the ranges in each list
                    line1=str(line)  
                    row1=str(row)  
                    outF.append(row1+"\t"+line1)
```

-I realize this is horribly inefficient, but I need to find all instances of when the first range overlaps with the ranges of the other file
-Is reading in each file line by line the fastest way? if not, what would the best data structure be for entire file
-should the lines be in a different data structure other than lists?

THANK YOU if you have any feedback!

aside: the purpose is to label a range of numbers if the numbers are found in the ranges of the other file(long story; maybe not relevant?)

Comment: I didn't understood the first paragraph of your description. Is it like you are iterating on first file then for each word, your are using inner loop to iterate another file? If that's the case then overall time complexity would be polynomial which is not that inefficient.

Comment: Sample data from both the files would have been useful to decide on data-structure but I still think list would suffice.

Comment: I didnt explain it very well in retrospect! @Welbog explained my problem very well below. Thank you for feedback!

Comment: i think i figured out how to make it really efficient by 'picking up' where i left off in the inner labeling loop instead of starting from 0 by sorting the query data. i really appreciate the help. lol i did it in R instead and it took like 2 min (R had a really efficient vector search)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your goal seems to be to find whether one range (`row[3] to row[4]`) overlaps with another (`line[1]-50 to line[1]`). For this, it is sufficient to that that either `line[1]-50` or `row[3]` lies inside the other range. This eliminates the third nested loop.

Also, take the 2-million-line file and sort it, once, and then use the sorted list inside your 3000-line loop to do a binary search, cutting from a O(nm) algorithm to an O(nlogm) one.

(My Python is far from perfect, but this should get you going in the right direction.)

```
with open("...") as label:
  reader = csv.reader(label, delimiter="\t")
  lines = list(reader)
  lines.sort(key=lambda line: int(line[1]))

for row in read_FIMO:
  # Find the nearest, lesser value in lines smaller than row[3]
  line = binary_search(lines, int(row[3]))

  # If what you're after is multiple matches, then
  # instead of getting a single line, get the smallest and 
  # largest indexes whose ranges overlap (which you can do with a 
  # binary search for row[3] and row[4]+50)
  # e.g.,
  # smallestIndex = binary_search(lines, int(row[3]))
  # largestIndex = binary_search(lines, int(row[4])+50)
  # for index in range(smallestIndex, largestIndex+1):

  lower1 = int(line[1] - 50)
  lower2 = int(row[3])
  upper1 = int(line[1])
  upper2 = int(row[4])
  if (lower1 > lower2 and lower1 < upper1) or (lower2 > lower1 and lower2 < upper2):
    line1=str(line)  
    row1=str(row)  
    outF.append(row1+"\t"+line1)
```

Comment: 1) you explained my problem way better than I did. 2)I did not have the 2 mill line file sorted and that is a great suggestion 3)I did NOT need the third inner loop. Thank you and I am going to test this out

Comment: i think the if statements are a bit off, but I get your point: the lower or upper just has to be in between a range.

Answer (score 0):

I think am  efficient way would be...

1. Going through the destination file first and record all the labels
   to a dictionary hash. `[LabelName] -> [Line number]`
2. Go through each line of the source and lookup the line from the
   dictionary and print (or print something else if not found)

**Notes / Tips**

- I think the above would be O(n)
- You could also go through the source file first and record then go through the destination file. This would create a smaller dictionary (and use less memory) but the output may not be in the order you would like. (smaller data sets often have better cache hits ratios so this is why I bring this up.)
- Also, only because you mentioned `most efficient`, and if you want to get crazy, I would try skipping the line by line processing, and just go through the input like it is one big string. Search for a new line char + white-space + a label name. Using this tip kind of depends what the input data looks like though. If the  "csv.reader" already does parse by line then this would not be good.  Also, you may need a lower level language with more control to do this method. (Caution: 90% chance this tip would just lead you to a rabbit hole that goes no-where)

Comment: i *think* the problem with this is that the ranges don't perfectly match the ranges of the labels. i like the dictionary idea. i think i figured out how to make it really efficient by 'picking up' where i left off in the inner labeling loop instead of starting from 0 by sorting the query data

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/SunsetQuest/CudaPAD/blob/0b143fc372977acec3d1c19604083bcc0efc6636/CudaPAD/MainForm.cs#L673) is where I did something similar.  I was compiling to assembly and [creating visual lines](https://github.com/SunsetQuest/CudaPAD/blob/0b143fc372977acec3d1c19604083bcc0efc6636/CudaPAD/MainForm.cs#L919) that would go between the source file and the asm file so the view can see how the lines match up. A dictionary hash was not used since I did not need it.